# Apache rewrite rules in htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am working in a project where we use codeigniter.

If user goto http://www.example.com/products.html link then my router look like is

```
$route['product'] = "product/all_product";
```

If they click any category say computer the (s)he will redirect to  http://www.example.com/computer.html and my router is

```
$route['category/(:any)'] = "product/category_product/$1"; //$1 = computer or electronics
```

How to do that using .htaccess file?

Comment: You need to rewrite all routes to index.php file, then CI has its own "rewriting mechanism" which it uses.

Comment: I'm sorry but that makes no sense what so ever. If the user is redirected to `http://www.mysite.com/computer.html`, what does `$route['category/(:any)'] = "product/category_product/$1";` have to do with that?

Comment: @Stanyer redirect means  when user visit www.mysite.com/computer.html link then my router will be $route['category/(:any)'] = "product/category_product/$1";

Comment: @SKG - `$route['category/(:any)']` will not do anything to a page named computer.html

Comment: @Stanyer - that is my question that using .htaccess rules how to do that ? When user visit http://www.mysite.com/computer.html page usign .htacess how to rewrite it http://www.mysite.com/computer .

Comment: If you're using PHP, why would the page be called computer.html?

Comment: why is there an `html` extension in the firstplace, codeigniter does not show the extension, only the `index.php` part, but if you remove it using `htaccess` you will have the `mysite.com/computer` already.

Answer (score 0):

@SKG - the url for your codeigniter site will be mysite.com/index.php. You can (and most people do) remove the index.php, so the default url is simply mysite.com

from there, if you have a controller Category with an index($var) function, you can access it via: mysite.com/category/(var)

if you have an existing page at mysite.com/computer.html and you would like it to go to mysite.com/category/(:any) - perhaps because that link is already "out in the wild" in many places and so you want to redirect people to the new url, then you'll want to do the redirect where the computer.html file is and then remap, as shown here:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html